# Link static archive with libc++ chrono and Xcode 10

Tags: c++, xcode, static-libraries, linker-errors

I have a c++ core library A that I put into a .a static archive. I'm trying to link this archive to a second swift project B which uses C bindings to library A. It all worked fine until I added some libc++ chrono references to the c++ core library. On itself A compiles fine, but when I link to project B, there is no symbols for chrono anymore.

I've tried putting chrono inside the header file, and cpp file. Modified Xcode build settings to use libc++ all around and always with same result:

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::chrono::steady_clock::now()", referenced from:
      utility::stopwatch::reset() in libtest.a(test.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

I can use chrono directly inside project A and B, but not add it to A and use it from B. How come? I'm at a bit of a loss.

/updates:

Using Xcode 10

Steps to reproduce:

1) create a new workspace A

2) create a new static library c++ project B and add it to workspace A and add two files:

```
// test.h

extern "C" {
    void using_chrono();
}

// test.cpp

#include <chrono>

void using_chrono() {
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
}
```

3) create a second swift project C and add it to workspace A too.

4) create a bridging header Bridging-Header.h with the following:

```
// Bridging-Header.h

void using_chrono();
```

5) build B

6) link the resulting .a archive to project C in build phase

7) add bridging header to object-c bridging header option in build settings for project C

8) compile. project C can't find `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()`

I think it might have something to do with the C conversion with swift since the `steady_clock::now()` function is still using C++ symbol mangling, and swift needs pure C functions to import. I've tried wrapping `steady_clock::now()` by global class, extern "C", C wrappers, but it doesn't seem to compile (wrapping in C didn't work at all due to chrono templates). durations and time_point et al seems to work fine, but not `now()`.

Comment: We'll probably need specific reproduction steps in order to help

Comment: version of Xcode? have you updated the command-line tools? Have you set the c++ standard version correctly for this target?

Comment: I was analyzing the symbols generated by the C++ project library with ```nm``` and it seems like steady_clock::now() is still being c++-mangled. Its a static function so even wrapping it in an extern "C" function doesn't seem to help. Might explain why the symbol can't be found from swift.

Comment: Many hours later I found that it works perfectly using a dynamic library instead. It makes sense because the code is compiled in project B before getting imported in project C. So the solution is some combination of my comment above and switching to a dynamic library for these sorts of projects. I'll probably add this as an answer unless someone beats me to it or have a better idea.